# VBA Internet Explorer - do not update data after button click in web page

Tags: vba, web

I am using VBA to get some information from a web page.
The code follow the steps:

1. open a web page (the default page show data 11/04/2018 (yesterday)
2. set date to 09/04/2018 (“dd/mm/yyyy”)
3. click OK button
4. take a value from loaded page
   The problem is the returned value is not from 09/04/2018 but from 11/04/2018 (default page).

The code is from a newbie and adapted from internet searchs.

```
Option Explicit

Declare Sub sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwmilliseconds As Long)

Sub IE_automacao()

Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objColletion1 As Object
Dim objColletion2 As Object
Dim x As Object
Dim y As Object
Dim i As Long

'Create Internet Explorer object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

'IE.navigate "http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/consultas/mercado-de-derivativos/contratos-em-aberto/por-tipo-de-participante/"
IE.navigate "http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-tipo-de-participante-ptBR.asp"

sleep (5000) 'wait 5 seconds to load web page


Set objColletion1 = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("input") 'set field in a object

i = 0
While i < objColletion1.Length 'try to find out field named "dData1"
    If objColletion1(i).Name = "dData1" Then
        ' set the date
        objColletion1(i).Value = "09/04/2018" 'a date before today

    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

Set objColletion2 = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("button") 'set the buttons on page

i = 0
While i < objColletion2.Length 'try to fid out the button to submit
    If objColletion2(i).Type = "submit" And objColletion2(i).Name = "" Then
        'OK button found
        Set objElement = objColletion2(i)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

objElement.Click 'OK button clicked

sleep (5000) 'wait to load  web page

For Each x In IE.document.body.getelementsbytagname("table") 'search for a expected value
    If InStr(x.innertext, "MERCADO FUTURO DE DÓLAR") > 0 Then
        For Each y In x.getelementsbytagname("tr")
            If InStr(y.innertext, "Inv. Não Residente") > 0 Then
                MsgBox y.getelementsbytagname("td")(1).innertext
            End If
        Next y
    End If
Next x

Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objColletion1 = Nothing
Set objColletion2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many expected but this works:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Sub sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwmilliseconds As Long)

Sub IE_automacao()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objColletion1 As Object
    Dim objColletion2 As Object
    Dim x As Object
    Dim y As Object
    Dim i As Long

    'Create Internet Explorer object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-tipo-de-participante-ptBR.asp"

    sleep (5000)                                 'wait 5 seconds to load web page 
    Dim n As Object
    Set n = IE.document.getelementbyID("dData1")
    n.Focus
    n.Value = "09/04/2018"


    Set objColletion2 = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("button") 'set the buttons on page

    i = 0
    While i < objColletion2.Length               'try to fid out the button to submit
        If objColletion2(i).Type = "submit" And objColletion2(i).Name = "" Then
            'OK button found
            Set objElement = objColletion2(i)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    objElement.Click                             'OK button clicked

    sleep (5000)                                 'wait to load  web page

    For Each x In IE.document.body.getelementsbytagname("table") 'search for a expected value
        If InStr(x.innertext, "MERCADO FUTURO DE DÓLAR") > 0 Then
            For Each y In x.getelementsbytagname("tr")
                If InStr(y.innertext, "Inv. Não Residente") > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print y.getelementsbytagname("td")(1).innertext
                    MsgBox y.getelementsbytagname("td")(1).innertext
                End If
            Next y
        End If
    Next x

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this please?